# FB.getLoginStatus with "force"=true only working for some usersadmins when used twice

Tags: facebook

We have a requirement on our site which forces a user to like a fan page before they can proceed on our site. Since Facebook requires a user to allow access via an app for this type of data, we have an initial call to FB.getLoginStatus which sends the user down three paths, based on the 3 responses (unknown, not connected, connected). Our problem exists in the "unknown" branch. This initial call to FB.getLoginStatus works fine for everyone, if the user is unknown (logged out) we show them the Like Box social widget, then the user clicks on it and logs in (thus liking the page), and then we use the callback of FB.Event.Subscribe('edge.create') to run FB.getLoginStatus again (to check if the user was simply logged out but has previously allowed our app). At that point, if the user previously allowed our app, we allow them to continue, if not we show them an "allow" button and on that user interaction and callback we allow the user to continue. This logic flow works for a hand full of people, including a few of the administrators listed for the app, but not the majority of users. On the second call to FB.getLoginStatus we are using the second parameter "force=true". Can anyone give insight into this behavior and/or point to a thread with a similar glitch? Thanks in advance, this one is a head scratcher!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a *white* hat technique and allowed by Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {

      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

      } else {


      }
     }, {force: 'true'});
```